# $n$ balls of $2^{n}-1$ colors, order not significant, how many combinations?

Tags: combinatorics

An example:

With $n = 3$,
We draw 3 balls. There are 7 different colors (or numbers). The order of balls does not matter, so [red, green, blue] is treated as being equal to [green, red, blue]. Colors could repeat, i.e. [gray, gray, gray] is a valid draw.

How do we calculate the total number of variations possible?

Comment: Sorry, didn't know there were two SE sites for math -- yes please.

Comment: [Mathematica.SE] is in fact *not* for math per se, but rather for the Wolfram Research software product *Mathematica*.

Comment: I used the probability tag as I was at a loss for a better tag. This is not about how probable an event is, it is about how many different triplets are possible to form.

Comment: Okay.  I believe the combinatorics tag I added is appropriate.  Nevertheless I still feel that the problem is underspecified.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I edited my comment above, if the goal is still unclear I could provide more details.

Comment: Perhaps you could give the known value you desire for `n = 2`.  Is it six, for this list of possible draws?:  {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 3}}

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, exactly. Since {1,2}={2,1}, {1,3}={3,1}, and {2,3}={3,2} we are left with 6 distinct combinations out of the 9 if order did matter.

Comment: I did try to go up to 3, but that is too many combinations (343).

Comment: Okay, please tell me if you believe this problem can be stated as follows: How many $n$ digit numbers are there in base $2^n-1$ where each digit (right to left or left to right; it doesn't matter) is greater or equal to the prior digit?

Comment: Actually, this did begin with numbers rather than balls. The original problem is: How many ways can we select n non-zero binary numbers of order n - the order of picks in each group does not matter.

Comment: I believe Keeran Brabazon in the answer below cast the problem exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the number of balls of each colour is assumed to be greater than the number of balls that you draw out then this is a matter of combinations with unlimited repetition. We can consider the equivalent problem of deciding how many ways we can distribute $n$ balls into $2^{n} -1$ boxes as follows

$$\underline{\lVert\text{colour 1}\rVert\text{colour 2}\rVert\text{colour 3}\rVert \ldots \lVert\text{colour }2^{n}-1\rVert }$$

Where "colour 1" indicates that the balls in this box have colour 1, etc.

If we replace the representation of the separators by 1's and the representation of the number of balls in a box by a sequence of zeros (e.g. sequence starting 1001101... means that there are two balls of colour 1 chosen, no balls of colour two and one ball of colour 3 then we can consider the problem of counting the number of possible sequences of $n$ zeros and $2^{n} - 2$ ones. This is simply

$\displaystyle C(2^{n} + n - 2, n) =\frac{(2^{n} + n - 2)!}{(2^{n} -2)!n!}$

(this is read  "Choose $n$ items from a set of $2^{n}+n-2$ items")

Comment: This fits my understanding of the question as well.

Comment: I tried to follow the reasoning, but didn't come out not feeling dizzy ;) The formula does give `6` for `n=2` however, which is right.

Comment: @MajidFouladpour If you can understand that the number of sequences of zeros and ones is the same as the number of ways of picking coloured balls from a bag, then you have got the hardest bit of the explanation above. The rest of it comes from the definition of a combination, which would be best to get from a textbook on discrete mathematics. The explanation on Wikipedia doesn't give too gentle an introduction

Comment: For `n=3`, we have `7 colors`, if I understand your notation correctly, then a sample draw would be shown as e.g. `10111010111`, right? Meaning the `1`s are walls providing a pidgin-hole like container for the balls, and since here we have 7 colors, we need 8 walls?

Comment: Yes that is right. Note that the first and the last wall (or 1) will always be there, so we in fact only consider the separators between the boxes (if there are $n$ boxes there will be $n-1$ separators). This is why we consider positioning $2^{n}-2$ ones, and not $2^{n}$. I hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for both this bright and geeky answer, and the suggestion to grab a textbook for exploring this area -- I am beginning to love this `combinatorics`, and I have picked [Mathematics for Informatics and Computer Science](http://www.amazon.com/Mathematics-Informatics-Computer-Science-ISTE/dp/1848211961/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1390864260&sr=8-1&keywords=Mathematics+for+Informatics+and+Computer+Science+%28ISTE%29).